# Using System.exit(n) to return value to Unix shell script

Tags: java, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to use `System.exit(n)` to return various error codes. I need to do this to access these numbers from a Unix shell script.

So for instance in my java program I have `System.exit(2)`.

Then in my shell script I have:

```
var=$(java myProgram arguments)
```

Which when ran will exit the java program using System.exit(2), shouldn't it output the integer 2 to "var"?  Because it doesn't. Am I missing something? What do I need to do to get it to give me the integer?

Comment: that shell syntax assigns the printed output from the sub-command to var.  you want `$?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

var=$( ... )

captures the **text** written to standard output. The **numeric** exit status is returned separately, and can be accessed as the value of the shell variable $?

Beware that for a non-interactive shell (that is, if this command is contained in a script), a non-zero exit status will by default terminate the script. You can forestall the automatic termination by using the command in a conditional. For example:

var=$( ... ) || echo The exit code was $?

Comment: Ah okay, that's why. So I'm going to run a bunch of these java commands in one script, how can I get $? each time? I'm confused on how to access this.

Comment: @user3059869 `$?` will give you the return value of the last command that ran. Just keep reading it after each command. `var=$?` will store the number in `var`.